# Calling useRef inside a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I've been out of react since before hooks and haven't used threeJS before, but I'm trying to hit 2 birds with one stone so excuse me if it's a rookie mistake.

what I'm trying to do is render a Three.js scene inside a react document body, how I'm trying to do that is through running the three.js code in `useEffect()` and setting a reference to my react document using useRef(), however, apparently useEffect runs before the document is rendered, hence breaking, so I tried using a ref callback like this

```js
import { useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
// Packages
import * as THREE from "three";
// Styling
import "./homePage.scss";

function HomePage() {
  // Declare a new mounting reference
  const mountRef = useCallback((node) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      useRef(null);
    }
  }, []);
  // Lifecycle hook
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(mountRef);
    // === THREE.JS CODE START ===
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // use ref as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
    mountRef.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    camera.position.z = 5;
    var animate = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    animate();
    // === THREE.JS CODE END ===
  }, []);

  return <div ref={mountRef} />;
}

export default HomePage;
```

However, now I have the following error
`React Hook "useRef" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook`

How can I fix this situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `useRef` at the top level of your component, not in a callback (don't use `useCallback` for it):

```
const mountRef = useRef(null);
```

Then in your `useEffect`, declare `mountRef.current` as a dependency and only use it if it exists, see `***` comments:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // *** If we don't have the DOM element yet, wait for it
    if (!mountRef.current) {
        return;
    }
    // === THREE.JS CODE START ===
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        1000
    );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // use ref as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
    mountRef.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    //      ^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− *** Use the DOM element
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    camera.position.z = 5;
    var animate = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    animate();
    // === THREE.JS CODE END ===
}, []);
```

You probably want to include a cleanup callback (a function you return from `useEffect`) to remove the Three DOM element from the `div` on unmount:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ***
    const { current } = mountRef;
    if (!current) {
        return;
    }
    // === THREE.JS CODE START ===
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        1000
    );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // use ref as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
    // ***
    const {domElement} = renderer;
    current.appendChild(domElement);
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    camera.position.z = 5;
    var animate = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    animate();
    // === THREE.JS CODE END ===
    // ***
    return () => {
        current.removeChild(domElement);
    };
}, []);
```

Note there how I grabbed `mountRef.current` and `renderer.domElement` to local constants. That makes the cleanup callback more reliable, since those properties can be changed outside the context of the `useEffect` callback.

Live Example:

```js
const {useRef, useEffect} = React;

function HomePage() {
    // Declare a new mounting reference
    const mountRef = useRef(null);
    // Lifecycle hook
    useEffect(() => {
        const { current } = mountRef;
        console.log("current", current);
        // If we don't have the DOM element yet, wait for it
        if (!current) {
            return;
        }
        // === THREE.JS CODE START ===
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            75,
            window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
            0.1,
            1000
        );
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        // use ref's DOM ELEMENT as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
        const { domElement } = renderer;
        current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(cube);
        camera.position.z = 5;
        var animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };
        animate();
        // === THREE.JS CODE END ===
        // Cleanup callback on component unmount
        return () => {
          current.removeChild(domElement);
        };
    }, []);
   
    return <div ref={mountRef} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <HomePage/>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r124/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I got a warning on your dependency which I didn't quite get why is necessary, but removing it still has everything working fine

Comment: React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'mountRef.current'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Mutable values like 'mountRef.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component

Comment: Yes It's definitely working fine without dependencies and you can see in the error message I had the right one

Comment: @OmarHussein - *Doh!* No, the dependency isn't needed, because the ref is used unconditionally, and the `useEffect` callback won't be called until [*"...after the render is committed to the screen...*](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect). Sorry about that!

Comment: no worries :D thanks for your help and explanation <3

Comment: I used your code and I get (Property 'appendChild' does not exist on type 'never'.) !!! any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @SaajidAkram - You're using TypeScript, which means you have to tell TS what the ref will refer to. Typically you do that with a *type argument* on `useRef`. For instance, if you were going to use the ref on a [`div`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) (as in this question), that's an `HTMLDivElement`, so you'd use `const mountRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);`. The type of `mountRef.current` will be `HTMLDivElement | null`, so you'd want to use destructuring and a guard (as in the second `useEffect` example) so TypeScript can narrow the type.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The code now is working .. However, for some reason, when I refresh the page the canvas will disappear and that happens also when I recompile the code. It is only when I try to output the canvas to the console then the object will be rendered!!! Do you know what causes that?

Comment: @SaajidAkram - Not without seeing the code, no. I suggest doing more searching and debugging, and if you can't figure it out create a **runnable** [mre] and post it in a new question. You can do that with Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Hi Crowder. here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-burnell-3if54?file=/src/Viewport.tsx) to the project ... when you open it, nothing will load, but as soon as you add console.log (current) after (if(current)) you'll see the box ... what did I do wrong in your opinion?

Comment: @SaajidAkram - Not offsite, a question **here**, using Stack Snippets. Please see the links I gave you above.

Comment: There you go :: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70504678/react-component-with-three-js-canvas-is-working-but-not-every-time)

Answer (score 1):

You can't define hooks in callbacks, see [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

To get the `div` ref, you only need to provide the reference from `useRef`, no `useCallback` needed at all, see [docs examples](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

```
const mountRef = useRef(null);
<div ref={mountRef} />
```

Comment: also you can't call it conditinally