# React component with Three.js canvas is working but NOT every time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js

So I have the following react component which allows me to append three.js canvas to a ref object of type HTMLDivElement:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as THREE from 'three';

export default function Viewport() {
  const mountRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const { current } = mountRef;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!current) { return; }

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, current.clientWidth / current.clientHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    const { domElement } = renderer;
    renderer.setClearColor(0xfff5ff,1)
    renderer.setSize(current.clientWidth, current.clientHeight);
    current.appendChild(domElement);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    camera.position.z = 5;
    var animate = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    
    animate();

    return () => {
      current.removeChild(domElement);
    };

  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={mountRef} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The component works, but not every time I mount it! this is the output "Most of the time":
[image: The component is mounted but the canvas is not there]
If I just add:

```
    console.log(current);
```

The code would work just fine, and the HTMLDivElement object will be printed out to the console!
[image]
[image]
What am I missing here?

Here is a CodeSandBox link to the project:
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-burnell-3if54?file=/src/Viewport.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing over a stale copy of the `current` property of `mountRef`. The initial value of `current` is `null`, which is what you get the first time you grab it on the next line. Then React renders your component and sets `current` to refer to the `div`, and *then* your `useEffect` callback is called — but it still has `null`.

Instead, use the updated property in the `useEffect` callback; see comments:

```typescript
export default function Viewport() {
  const mountRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  // Don't grab `current` here

  useEffect(() => {
    // Grab it here
    const { current } = mountRef;
    if (!current) { return; }
    // ...
```

Comment: Certainly works. Very grateful to you, Crowder ... Thank you so much.